# forEach in Array (in) Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I want to search words in headlines of my posts and if it contains Names example: max or Marry, it should add Photo from them.

```
    var imageLocation = document.querySelectorAll(".summary"); // where Image should be added
    var headLines = document.querySelectorAll(".ecs-thumbnail");// where my Names are.
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");

   headlines.forEach(function (pos){
      const txt = pos.innerText;
      var max = txt.includes("max");
      var marry = txt.includes("marry");

    if(marry === true){
    pos.parentNode.childNodes[1].prepend(img);
    img.setAttribute("src", "https://dev.musikzentrum-hannover.de/wp-content/uploads/marry.png");
      } else if(max === true){
      pos.parentNode.childNodes[1].prepend(imgAus);
    img.setAttribute("src", "https://dev.musikzentrum-hannover.de/wp-content/uploads/max.png");
      }
    })
```

it Works, but I have many Headlines in the class and it adds Pictures just to the last Elements of class.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. Not sure why you work innerText to get a value and decide upon that. Please try to re-phrase your question.

Comment: I just edited my Text. sorry ;)
and Thanks in advance

Comment: The if statement doesn't look right. if and else if test for the same condition, so the latter will never be executed; also you're overwriting the last inserted img DOM element over and over and keep adding it.

Comment: Not sure I got your question correctly. But it is highly likely that you need to move image creation to the iteratee function. `var img = document.createElement("IMG");` should be created for each element if needed.

Comment: @TheCoprolal, what do you suggest?

Comment: @hamid `if(max === true){ } else if(max === true){}` makes no sense. Should be `} else if(marry){`

Comment: First: ist there a name?
Second: which Name?
now add a picture of this name to its Parent. (and it continues...)

Comment: @TheCoprolal your right, edited it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several lines that don't look right. The if/else if test for the same condition. The same image DOM element is modified and prepended over and over again. The variable names don't match, headlines vs headLines. imageLocation is never used. This might work:

```
var headLines = document.querySelectorAll(".ecs-thumbnail");// where my Names are.

headLines.forEach(function (pos){
    let src;
    if(pos.innerText.includes("marry")){
        src = "https://dev.musikzentrum-hannover.de/wp-content/uploads/marry.png";
    } else if(pos.innerText.includes("max")) {
        src = "https://dev.musikzentrum-hannover.de/wp-content/uploads/max.png";
    }

    if(src) {
        let img = document.createElement("IMG");
        img.setAttribute("src", src);
        pos.parentNode.childNodes[1].prepend(img);
    }
});
```